# Can I use NVidia Mellanox networking cards in the 2023 Apple Mac Pro (25G, 40G, 50G, 100G, 200G)?

Tags: network, hardware, mac-pro

I am wondering if the NVidia Mellanox 100G network cards can be used in the 2023 Mac Pro. In an older thread on the Nvidia forums titled "100g connectX 5 slow speed between Mac to Proxmox TrueNAS VM" the answer was "[At this moment NVIDIA ConnectX Adapters are not supported on the Mac OS platform](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/100g-connectx-5-slow-speed-between-mac-to-proxmox-truenas-vm/244161/1)".

On the [Sonnet Desktop website](https://www.sonnettech.com/support/downloads/manuals/TB_PCIe_Card_Compatibility.pdf) the NVidia Mellanox 10G and 25G cards are mentioned as being supported.

Can anyone confirm or report on compatibility? [A thread in the Macrumors forums suggest that ATTO cards work](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/mellanox-connectx-3-40-gbe-using-atto-fastframe-macos-driver.2225779/page-3).

Answer (score 0):

Your [provided thread in the Macrumors forums](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/mellanox-connectx-3-40-gbe-using-atto-fastframe-macos-driver.2225779/page-3) suggests that ATTO cards do work. The thread is from 2020, so you should take into account that not all the information posted there up-to-date. The atto website features the [4th Generation FastFrame™ 10/25/40/50/100GbE SmartNICs](https://www.atto.com/products/ethernet-adapters) (PCIe 4.0 and 3.0), and the [specification of the Atto N412 mentions macOS driver support](https://www.atto.com/products/ethernet-adapters/fastframe3-10-25-40-50-100-gbe-nics/gen4-25-40-50-100gbe-nics/FFRM-N412-000). So this would be the proper source to look for (in regards to Atto).

Apple has a dedicated page titled [PCIe cards you can install in your Mac Pro (2023)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/101988). According to the technical specs of the Mac Pro 2023 it features "full length x16 gen4 slots", so the card you mentioned (MCX515A-CCAT) can be installed, as it features PCIe 3.0 x16.

Drivers for macOS are [NOT explicitly mentioned on the NVIDIA developer website for the Mellanox cards](https://developer.nvidia.com/networking/ethernet-software).

Atto is the only company supporting drivers for Apple Silicon at this point, so your best bet is to "crossflash". People are successfully flashing NVIDIA Mellanox ConnecX cards with Atto firmware, and it seems to work to some extent (see the thread [Mellanox ConnectX-3 40 GbE using ATTO FastFrame macOS driver](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/mellanox-connectx-3-40-gbe-using-atto-fastframe-macos-driver.2225779/page-3) you already provided). The FastFrame NQ41 and NQ42 are just rebranded Mellanox ConnectX-3 cards (same with FastFrame N311 and the ConnectX-4).

**To be very precise and to answer the question: there is no official support from NVIDIA regarding Apple Silicon drivers, but you can crossflash to Atto firmware.**